# IE6 hover state not reverting

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

**Demo**
http://people.mywot.com/dean/tour/ie6test.html

I have narrowed down this problem into the test case above. You'll spot it right away if you load it up in IE6.

**The problem**

When hovering over the anchor in IE6, all descendent elements which are meant to become visible become visible, but as soon as you hover out, all styling remains but the text disappears. This results in a "ghost box" and quite an interesting (but undesired effect).

I've searched for a few hours this morning to try and find out which [IE6 bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer.html) this is, but I'm out of ideas.

P.S. Ignore the transparency of the PNG's. I just haven't included the pngfix on this demo.

Comment: Do you mind showing us some code, I'm getting a headache looking through your resources.

Comment: What do you mean Dade? There is a demo in the first line of my post, with code provided.

Comment: I'm afraid my limited messing around hasn't been able to work it out. My only suggestion is to simplify the code by removing features one by one until the issue goes away: take away the graphics and CSS code around it until you've got as little there as possible but still got the bug; that will help you isolate it. It's a pain, but that's the reality of debugging in IE6. By the way, you are also suffering from the IE6 PNG transparency bug on your bubble graphics, but I think that's a separate issue. Google for IEPNGFIX to find solutions to that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 100% of webmaster hate the devil IE6, but we're here to answer the question, not to discuss how bad IE6 is, right?

And for the question, this is my answer : (Edited line 42 & 43 in your demo code)

```
...
    .screenshot a.bubble .description { position: absolute; min-width: 200px; bottom: -8px; background: none; display: none;
     }
    .screenshot a.bubble:hover .description { display: inline;  background: #efefef; }
...
```

I don't know how, but IE6 **cannot hide** the div with css property "background" not set to "none". That's all what cause the problem. Anyway, I hate IE6.

Comment: Thanks. I had to readjust a bit of CSS but this was the bug. To anyone else experiencing a similar issue, set your styles to off (border none, background none etc.) in the standard state, and then add them in the hover.

Answer (score 3):

Hover states in IE6 have some silly bugs unfortunately.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-hover covers most of them which should allow you to experiment with what might be wrong.

EDIT: You may have to resort to javascript to overcome this one unfortunately.

Some commenters are forgetting that there are a number of clients (eg: UK local government) that still almost exclusively use IE6. Pity those of us who have to still ensure it is taken into consideration!

Comment: For those who do still need to support IE6 for your site (or worse, use IE6 on a day-to-day basis), you have my deepest sympathy. I stick by my recommendation to drop IE6 for this particular project. Looking at the content of the demo site it seems unlikely that it's intended for use in a closed corporate environment, which would be the only case where I would consider IE6 support to still be necessary. Those organisations that are still requiring it are going to have a big shock when MS finishes their extended support for it in 2014.

Comment: From messaging the OP, this project appears to have a large enough client base on IE6 to warrant its support unfortunately. I personally will actually dance around the office on the day we are no longer required to support IE6, but it's still a long way off. Larger corporates & various governmental offices, at least in the UK, are still massively tied into it. It's going to cost them a lot in the long run, but until it comes to the crunch, we're stuck with supporting it.